# Is it possible to run valgrind on a portion of the code?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a memory leak that happens within a known section of fairly large system. I'd like to run full speed until that section of code, run valgrind memcheck on that section, and collect valgrind memcheck report at the end of said section without completing the run further. Is that possible?

Comment: Related: Even if this is possible, are both allocation *and* de-allocation *entirely* within to the code in question? If not, the number of false-positives could be painful.

Comment: @WhozCraig: the leaks I'm concerned about are most likely allocations within that code that *should have been* de-allocated within that code, but, apparently, were not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with memcheck, no. According to the [valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.attach), callgrind is currently the only valgrind component that supports this:

> **5.4. Is it possible to attach Valgrind to a program that is already running?**
>
> No. The environment that Valgrind provides for running programs is significantly different to that for normal programs, e.g. due to different layout of memory. Therefore Valgrind has to have full control from the very start.
>
> It is possible to achieve something like this by running your program without any instrumentation (which involves a slow-down of about 5x, less than that of most tools), and then adding instrumentation once you get to a point of interest. Support for this must be provided by the tool, however, and Callgrind is the only tool that currently has such support. See the instructions on the `callgrind_control` program for details.